# R: colClasses for multiple columns

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I am trying to set colClasses in the read.csv function, and I want to set multiple columns to the same type. What I tried was creating a vector of the names of the columns I want to set the type to, and did this:

```
col.names <- c("name1", "name2", "name3")
test.read <- read.csv("file.csv", colClasses = c(col.names = "character"))
```

However, this always gives the warning: Warning message:

```
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  not all columns named in 'colClasses' exist.
```

I tried putting the column names, which then it works.

```
test.read <- read.csv("file.csv", colClasses = c("name1" = "character", "name2" = "character", "name3" = "character"))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

On the other hand, this is an unrelated question, but is there a way to get the number of columns in a .csv file without having to actually reading it and using ncol?

Comment: If you run `c(col.names = "character")` in your console, I think the warning will make more sense.

Comment: I just tried it and saw what happened... is there way to prevent "col.names" itself from being concatenated into a string?

Comment: I suppose you could use `colClasses = sapply(col.names, function(x) "character")` to preserve the names attribute, but it may just be easier to construct `col.names` properly in the first place, e.g. `col.names <- rep("character", 3); names(col.names) <- c("name1", "name2", "name3")`.